# Pandas Multiple Conditions Function based on Column

Tags: python, pandas

Just trying to find the most elegant way to apply a really simple transformation to values in different columns with each column having it's own condition. So given a dataframe like this:

```
   A      B      C  D    E     F
0  1 2013-01-02  1  3   test  foo
1  1 2013-01-02  1  3  train  foo
2  1 2013-01-02  1  3   test  foo
3  1 2013-01-02  1  3  train  foo
```

Just want to have a function that will adjust the values in each column only if a second column has a specific value. In other words...

```
df['C'] = -1 if df['E'] == "test" else df['C'] next column...
df['D'] = -2 if df['E'] == "test" else df['D'] and so forth.
```

I was thinking the where function in pandas would come in handy here but wasn't sure how to apply it. I could do the below but does not seem very efficient and I would have to create a different function for each col:

```
def col(df):
    if df['col1'] == "value":
        return -1.00
    else:
        return relative_buckets['col1']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.loc` with a boolean series:

```
>>> df
   A           B  C  D      E    F
0  1  2013-01-02  1  3   test  foo
1  1  2013-01-02  1  3  train  foo
2  1  2013-01-02  1  3   test  foo
3  1  2013-01-02  1  3  train  foo
>>> df.loc[df.E == "test", "C"] = -1
>>> df
   A           B  C  D      E    F
0  1  2013-01-02 -1  3   test  foo
1  1  2013-01-02  1  3  train  foo
2  1  2013-01-02 -1  3   test  foo
3  1  2013-01-02  1  3  train  foo
```

Using `.loc` is preferable to trying to affect columns directly because of view vs. copy issues (see [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy) for the gory details.)

If you want to change multiple columns at once, you can do that too:

```
>>> df.loc[df.E == "test", ["C","D"]] = [888, 999]
>>> df
   A           B    C    D      E    F
0  1  2013-01-02  888  999   test  foo
1  1  2013-01-02    1    3  train  foo
2  1  2013-01-02  888  999   test  foo
3  1  2013-01-02    1    3  train  foo
```

Comment: nice! was looking for that multi-column change with a one liner! very cool. thanks.