# Replace values in observations (i.e., multiple columns within multiple rows) based on multiple conditionals

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to replace the values of 3 columns within multiple observations based on two conditionals ( e.g., specific ID after a particular date).

I have seen similar questions.

1. [Pandas Multiple Conditions Function based on Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28910954/pandas-multiple-conditions-function-based-on-column)
2. [Pandas replace, multi column criteria](http://Pandas%20replace,%20multi%20column%20criteria)
3. [Pandas: How do I assign values based on multiple conditions for existing columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30631841/pandas-how-do-i-assign-values-based-on-multiple-conditions-for-existing-columns)
4. [Replacing values in a pandas dataframe based on multiple conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55081194/replacing-values-in-a-pandas-dataframe-based-on-multiple-conditions)

However, they did not quite address my problem or I can't quite manipulate them to solve my problem.

***This code will generate a dataframe similar to mine:***

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'SUR_ID': {0:'SUR1', 1:'SUR1', 2:'SUR1', 3:'SUR1', 4:'SUR2', 5:'SUR2'}, 'DATE': {0:'05-01-2019', 1:'05-11-2019', 2:'06-15-2019', 3:'06-20-2019', 4: '05-15-2019', 5:'06-20-2019'}, 'ACTIVE_DATE': {0:'05-01-2019', 1:'05-01-2019', 2:'05-01-2019', 3:'05-01-2019', 4: '05-01-2019', 5:'05-01-2019'}, 'UTM_X': {0:'444895', 1:'444895', 2:'444895', 3:'444895', 4: '445050', 5:'445050'}, 'UTM_Y': {0:'4077528', 1:'4077528', 2:'4077528', 3:'4077528', 4: '4077762', 5:'4077762'}})
```

**Output Dataframe:**

[image]

***What I am trying to do:***

I am trying to replace *UTM_X*,*UTM_Y*, AND *ACTIVE_DATE*  with

> [444917, 4077830, '06-04-2019']

when

> *SUR_ID* is "SUR1" and *DATE* >= "2019-06-04 12:00:00"

***This is a poorly adapted version of the solution for question 1 in attempts to fix my problem- throws error:***

```
df.loc[[df['SUR_ID'] == 'SUR1' and df['DATE'] >='2019-06-04 12:00:00'], ['UTM_X', 'UTM_Y', 'Active_Date']] = [444917, 4077830, '06-04-2019']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First ensure that the column Date is of type datetime, and then when using 2 conditions, they need to be between parenthesis individually. so you can do:

```
df.DATE = pd.to_datetime(df.DATE)
df.loc[ (df['SUR_ID'] == 'SUR1') & (df['DATE'] >= pd.to_datetime('2019-06-04 12:00:00')), 
        ['UTM_X', 'UTM_Y', 'ACTIVE_DATE']] = [444917, 4077830, '06-04-2019']
```

See the difference between what you wrote for the boolean mask:

```
[df['SUR_ID'] == 'SUR1' and df['DATE'] >='2019-06-04 12:00:00']
```

and what is here with parenthesis

```
(df['SUR_ID'] == 'SUR1') & (df['DATE'] >= pd.to_datetime('2019-06-04 12:00:00'))
```

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Nice to know I wasn't too far of base.

Comment: I had date set to date time in the dataframe, but I did not set it to datetime in the conditional.

Comment: @DevonOliver indeed not too far :) and if your column DATE is already of datetime, then converting the string to datetime in the conditional may not be necessary, but it is more rigorous

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
df['UTM_X']=df['UTM_X'].mask(df['SUR_ID'].eq('SUR1') & (pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'])>= pd.to_datetime("2019-06-04 12:00:00")),444917)
df['UTM_Y']=df['UTM_Y'].mask(df['SUR_ID'].eq('SUR1') & (pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'])>= pd.to_datetime("2019-06-04 12:00:00")),4077830)
df['ACTIVE_DATE']=df['ACTIVE_DATE'].mask(df['SUR_ID'].eq('SUR1') & (pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'])>= pd.to_datetime("2019-06-04 12:00:00")),'06-04-2019')
```

Output:

```
    SUR_ID  DATE        ACTIVE_DATE UTM_X   UTM_Y
0   SUR1    05-01-2019  05-01-2019  444895  4077528
1   SUR1    05-11-2019  05-01-2019  444895  4077528
2   SUR1    06-15-2019  06-04-2019  444917  4077830
3   SUR1    06-20-2019  06-04-2019  444917  4077830
4   SUR2    05-15-2019  05-01-2019  445050  4077762
5   SUR2    06-20-2019  05-01-2019  445050  4077762
```